# mojolicious disable dot placeholder routing

Tags: perl, mojolicious

**Background**

I have this routing

`my $foo = $r->get('/foo/:asd')->to('Foo#bar');`

in the controller I'm just rendering some json with the passed param
(with the help of `Mojolicious::Controller::REST`)

`$self->data( 'param' => $self->param('asd') );`

**The Problem**

When sending a request to `/foo/bar`, its working as expected:

`{"data":{"param":"bar"}}`

but when I'm trying to pass a string that is containing a `dot`, an email for example (email@email.com), mojo is rendering the `dot` as a `slash`. The routing I defined in the first place is not longer relevant, because now the pattern has changed to `foo/:bar/:baz`

**The Solution**

I was told that the solution is around here:
https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/t/mojolicious/routes.t#L218 
It make sense, but I do not understand how to combine that with what I have.

I tried to add `$foo->pattern->placeholder_start('+');` to my routing, but still, the pattern is changing and its irrelevant all over again. It doesn't look like its going to disable the dot related to my problem.

I tried implement the pattern method on the `$r` variable (which is the Mojo's routing - `$self->routes`)

Bottom line, I just need to disable the dot placeholder for certain routing or entirely.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you say an email address like `email@email.com` has a colon?

Comment: sorry, I meant dot (`.`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mojolicious supports three kinds of placeholder parameters:

[Standard](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Standard-placeholders)

```
my $foo = $r->get('/foo/:asd')->to('Foo#bar');
```

[Relaxed](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Relaxed-placeholders)

```
my $foo = $r->get('/foo/#asd')->to('Foo#bar');
```

[Wildcards](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Wildcard-placeholders)

```
my $foo = $r->get('/foo/*asd')->to('Foo#bar');
```

Standard placeholders can match all characters except `.` and `/` .
Relaxed placeholders can match all characters except `/`.
Wildcard placeholders can match all characters. So if you want to support parameter values with `.` or `/`, you must use the relaxed or wildcard style placeholders.

Comment: I just realized the concept of the placeholders and the custom pattern now, I just didn't approached it the right way. Thank you.

Comment: What can you use when the parameter may start with a dot? It seems wildcard placeholders don't work in that case

Comment: I was looking for help with this for Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI. You add `"x-mojo-placeholder": "#"` in the parameter definition to specify relaxed parameters.