# OpenAPI: is it possible to include IP address (string with dots) in URL path?

Tags: perl, url, openapi, mojolicious

Using [`Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI), is it possible to include an IP address in a URL path (not query parameter)? As per [RFC 3986 §2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2), `.` is not a reserved character.

When I try:

```bash
curl 'localhost:3000/api/echo/192.168.1.1'
```

I get an http/404 `Not Found` error:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Not Found.",
            "path": "/"
        }
    ],
    "status": 404
}
```

What I expect is:

```json
{
    "ip": "192.168.1.1"
}
```

Here's a sample Mojolicious full-app:

`./api.yaml`

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.3
servers:
  - url: /api
info:
  version: 1
  title: MyAPI
paths:
  /echo/{ip}:
    get:
      x-mojo-to: Example#echo
      parameters:
      - name: ip
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
          format: ipv4
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '500':
          description: Internal Server Error
```

`./lib/MyApp.pm`

```perl
package MyApp;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious', -signatures;

sub startup ($self) {
  $self->plugin(OpenAPI => {url=>$self->home->rel_file("api.yaml")});
  $self->plugin(SwaggerUI => {route=>$self->routes()->any('/swagger'),url=>"/api"});
}

1;
```

`./lib/MyApp/Controller/Example.pm`

```perl
package MyApp::Controller::Example;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller', -signatures;

sub echo($self) {
  my $app   = $self->openapi->valid_input or return;
  my $input = $app->validation->output;
  my $ip    = $input->{ip};
  $app->render(openapi=>{ip=>$ip});
}

1;
```

Comment: This regex in variable name didn't work either: `/echo/{ip:.+}:`

Comment: I don't use Mojo, but in the curl call you use `hello`, but it looks like the route is `echo`. Is that your problem?

Comment: Thanks @stevieb. That was a copy-paste error. The issue has to do with `.` being treated as a file extension of sort. Using `in: query` and adjusting the `paths` to `/echo` works, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [mojo discussions](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/discussions/2103#discussioncomment-6977991) and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278138/2035207):

- [Standard](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Standard-placeholders) `:` placeholders can match all characters except `.` and `/`
- [Relaxed](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Relaxed-placeholders) `#` placeholders can match all characters except `/`
- [Wildcard](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Wildcard-placeholders) `*` placeholders can match all characters

So in my `api.yaml`, I need to set [`x-mojo-placeholder`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mojolicious-Plugin-OpenAPI/view/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI/Guides/OpenAPIv3.pod#Specification) to `"#"` (Relaxed)

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.3
servers:
  - url: /api
info:
  version: 1
  title: MyAPI
paths:
  /echo/{ip}:
    get:
      x-mojo-to: Example#echo
      parameters:
      - name: ip
        x-mojo-placeholder: "#"
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
          format: ipv4
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '500':
          description: Internal Server Error
```